Resizable Div Cursors
I am encountering an issue with my div that has 8 child elements that manage the resizing of there parent div. My issue is that the cursors do not seem to be working as expect because they are changing when exiting the div or hovering over one of the resizers. I want to say that the issue is with the stop resize but I am starting to doubt it as I have tried changing how its called and the actual code in there but neither worked.


const magicSquare = document.getElementById('magicSquare');
const minSize = 100;
const maxSize = 500;

const resizers = document.querySelectorAll('.resizer');
resizers.forEach(function(resizer) {
  resizer.addEventListener('mousedown', initResize);
});

function initResize(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const resizer = e.target;
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', resize);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResize);

  const originalWidth = magicSquare.offsetWidth;
  const originalHeight = magicSquare.offsetHeight;
  const originalMouseX = e.clientX;
  const originalMouseY = e.clientY;

  function resize(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const mouseX = e.clientX;
    const mouseY = e.clientY;
    let newWidth = originalWidth;
    let newHeight = originalHeight;

    if (resizer.classList.contains('bottom-right')) {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'se-resize';
      newWidth = originalWidth + 2 * (mouseX - originalMouseX);
      newHeight = originalHeight + 2 * (mouseY - originalMouseY);
    } else if (resizer.classList.contains('bottom-left')) {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'sw-resize';
      newWidth = originalWidth - 2 * (mouseX - originalMouseX);
      newHeight = originalHeight + 2 * (mouseY - originalMouseY);
    } else if (resizer.classList.contains('top-right')) {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'ne-resize';
      newWidth = originalWidth + 2 * (mouseX - originalMouseX);
      newHeight = originalHeight - 2 * (mouseY - originalMouseY);
    } else if (resizer.classList.contains('top-left')) {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'nw-resize';
      newWidth = originalWidth - 2 * (mouseX - originalMouseX);
      newHeight = originalHeight - 2 * (mouseY - originalMouseY);
    } else if (resizer.classList.contains('top')) {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'n-resize';
      newHeight = originalHeight - 2 * (mouseY - originalMouseY);
    } else if (resizer.classList.contains('right')) {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'e-resize';
      newWidth = originalWidth + 2 * (mouseX - originalMouseX);
    } else if (resizer.classList.contains('bottom')) {
      document.body.style.cursor = 's-resize';
      newHeight = originalHeight + 2 * (mouseY - originalMouseY);
    } else if (resizer.classList.contains('left')) {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'w-resize';
      newWidth = originalWidth - 2 * (mouseX - originalMouseX);
    }

    // Enforce minimum and maximum sizes
    if (newWidth < minSize) newWidth = minSize;
    if (newWidth > maxSize) newWidth = maxSize;
    if (newHeight < minSize) newHeight = minSize;
    if (newHeight > maxSize) newHeight = maxSize;

    magicSquare.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
    magicSquare.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
  }

  function stopResize() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', resize);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopResize);
    document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
  }
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#magicSquare {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.resizer {
  background: #333;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.resizer.top-left,
.resizer.top-right,
.resizer.bottom-left,
.resizer.bottom-right {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.resizer.top-left {
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  cursor: nw-resize;
}

.resizer.top-right {
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  cursor: ne-resize;
}

.resizer.bottom-left {
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  cursor: sw-resize;
}

.resizer.bottom-right {
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  cursor: se-resize;
}

.resizer.top {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 10px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  cursor: n-resize;
}

.resizer.right {
  width: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  right: -5px;
  top: 5px;
  cursor: e-resize;
}

.resizer.bottom {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 10px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  cursor: s-resize;
}

.resizer.left {
  width: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  left: -5px;
  top: 5px;
  cursor: w-resize;
}
<div id="magicSquare">
  <div class="resizer top-left"></div>
  <div class="resizer top-right"></div>
  <div class="resizer bottom-left"></div>
  <div class="resizer bottom-right"></div>
  <div class="resizer top"></div>
  <div class="resizer right"></div>
  <div class="resizer bottom"></div>
  <div class="resizer left"></div>
</div>



